# How to fix "No Graylog servers available. Cannot log in" in Graylog?

Tags: graylog2, graylog

After applied "echo -n password | sha256sum" now I am getting issue like
"No Graylog servers available. Cannot log in".

Could you find screen shot and server.conf file and web.conf files script.

In the server.conf file:

password_secret = sDk4hzCYXJ3auybi5ZBzNB65lvO62H81tr206vJ2uOB7g3i6IDmxvowXrzYqBhKHpGdOVbQyoO1G2v3rXQxwBDnX7SdxBPVE

root_password_sha2 = 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8

In the web.conf file :

application.secret="sDk4hzCYXJ3auybi5ZBzNB65lvO62H81tr206vJ2uOB7g3i6IDmxvowXrzYqBhKHpGdOVbQyoO1G2v3rXQxwBDnX7SdxBPVE"

In the Graylog welcome page showing 
with error like "No Graylog servers available. Cannot log in."

Could you please suggest me how to fix the issues:

1.No Graylog servers available. Cannot log in.
2.Sorry, those credentials are invalid

(here I used username:admin

password:5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8)

but I unble to login success in Graylog.

Thanks,
Nag